# What are some ways to speed up data loading on large sparse arrays (~1 million x 1 million, density ~0.0001) in Pytorch?

Tags: pytorch, bigdata, sparse-matrix

I am working on a binary classification problem. I have ~1.5 million data points, and the dimensionality of the feature space is 1 million. This dataset is stored as a sparse array, with a density of ~0.0001. For this post, I'll limit the scope to assume that the model is a shallow feedforward neural network, and also assume that the dimensionality has already been optimized (so cannot be reduced below 1 million). Naiive approaches to create mini-batches out of this data to feed into the network would take a lot of time (As an example, a basic approach of creating a `TensorDataset` (map style) from a `torch.sparse.FloatTensor` representation of the input array, and wrapping a `DataLoader` around it, means ~20s to get a mini-batch of 32 to the network, as opposed to say ~0.1s to perform the actual training). I am looking for ways to speed this up.

#### What I've tried

1. I first figured that reading from such a large sparse array in every iteration of the `DataLoader` was computationally intensive, so I broke down this sparse array into smaller sparse arrays
2. For the `DataLoader` to read from these multiple sparse arrays in an iterative fashion, I replaced the map style dataset that I had inside the `DataLoader` with an `IterableDataset`, and streamed these smaller sparse arrays into this IterableDataset like so:

```
from itertools import chain
from scipy import sparse

class SparseIterDataset(torch.utils.data.IterableDataset):
    
    def __init__(self, fpaths):
        super(SparseIter).__init__()
        self.fpaths = fpaths
    
    def read_from_file(self, fpath):
        data = sparse.load_npz(fpath).toarray()
        for d in data:
            yield torch.Tensor(d)
            
    def get_stream(self, fpaths):
        return chain.from_iterable(map(self.read_from_file, fpaths))
    
    def __iter__(self):
        return self.get_stream(self.fpaths)
```

With this approach, I was able to bring down the time from the naiive base case of ~20s to ~0.2s per minibatch of 32. However, given that my dataset has ~1.5 million samples, this still implies a lot of time spent on even making one pass through the dataset. (As a comparison, even though it's slightly apples to oranges, running a logistic regression on scikit-learn on the original sparse array takes about ~6s per iteration through the *whole dataset*. With pytorch, with the approach I just outlined, it would take ~3000s just to load all the minibatches in an epoch)

One thing which I am aware of but yet to try is using multiprocess data loading by setting the `num_workers` argument in the `DataLoader`. I believe this has its own catches in the case of iterable style datasets though. Plus even a 10x speedup would still mean ~300s per epoch in loading mini batches. I feel I'm being inordinately slow! Are there any other approaches/improvements/best practices that you could suggest?

Comment: Frankly this isn't that much data - it's what, 150m values? The big bottleneck is going to be that `toarray()` which will have to allocate just a horrifying amount of memory to hold all those zeros. Why don't you just push the coo indices directly into a `torch.sparse_coo_tensor`? I don't see any reason to have to densify this array.

Answer (score 3):

Your dataset in un-sparsified form would be 1.5M x 1M x 1 byte = 1.5TB as uint8, or 1.5M x 1M x 4 byte = 6TB as float32.  Simply reading 6TB from memory to CPU could take 5-10 minutes on a modern CPU (depending on the architecture), and transfer speeds from CPU to GPU would be a bit slower than that (NVIDIA V100 on PCIe has 32GB/s theoretical).

Approaches:

1. Benchmark everything individually - eg in jupyter

   %%timeit data = sparse.load_npz(fpath).toarray()

   %%timeit dense = data.toarray() # un-sparsify for comparison

   %%timeit t = torch.tensor(data) # probably about the same as the line above

Also **print out the shapes and datatypes** of everything to make sure they are as expected.  I haven't tried running your code but I am pretty sure that (a) sparse.load_npz is extremely fast and unlikely to be a bottleneck, but (b) torch.tensor(data) produces a dense tensor and is also quite slow here

2. Use [torch.sparse](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/sparse.html). I think torch sparse tensors can be used as regular tensors in most cases. You'd have to do some data prep to convert from scipy.sparse to torch.sparse:

> A sparse tensor is represented as a pair of dense tensors: a tensor of
> values and a 2D tensor of indices.  A **sparse tensor can be constructed by**
> **providing these two tensors**, as well as the size of the sparse tensor

You mention `torch.sparse.FloatTensor` but I'm pretty sure you're not making sparse tensors in your code - there is no reason to expect those would be constructed simply from passing a scipy.sparse array to a regular tensor constructor, since that's not how they're usually made.

If you figure out a good way to do this, I recommend you post it as a project or git on github, it would be quite useful.

3. If torch.sparse doesn't work out, think of other ways to either convert the data to dense only on the GPU, or avoid converting it entirely.

See also:
https://towardsdatascience.com/sparse-matrices-in-pytorch-be8ecaccae6
https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_sparse

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply! For point 2, I do not pass the scipy.sparse array into the tensor constructor, but pass its values and indices in (which is the recommended way) - I omitted this for the sake of brevity. The links you posted look interesting. I will get back on here as I explore this problem over the coming days.

Comment: @AbhimanyuSahai - How the `torch.sparse.FloatTensor` is constructed is the most important part, so please add that code.  The code sample you show converts the sparse to a dense, which sounds like is not what you intend.  That alone can account for the slow speed.